# Как убрать отступы у картинки по бокам в css?

Tags: html, css

Код html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>31three</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var preload = document.getElementById("preloader");
            var loading = 0;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 64);

        function frame() {
            if (loading == 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
            } else {
            loading = loading + 1;
            if (loading == 90) {
          preload.style.opacity = "0";
        }
      }
    }
  })();
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <img id="one" src="pictures/one.jpg">

</body>
</html>
```

Код css

```
body {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

В css ничего такого ещё не писал, потому что столкнулся с такой проблемкой и решил ничего пока что не нагружать, чтобы легче было понять другом код

Изображение, где показаны отступы
Масштаб сделан по умолчанию, у меня всегда 100

[image: Пример]

Comment: `body { margin: 0; }` не помогает?

Comment: `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: Да, спасибо, я уже сам разобрался. Только проблема в том, что при изменении масштаба всё остаётся на месте, а мне нужно, чтобы менялся размер, но страница оставалась прежней. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Изменение масштаба чего? Менялся размер чего? Отловить пользовательский zoom довольно проблемно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116221/prevent-zoom-cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

Есть решение вашей проблемы:

- Допишите в теге вашей картинки следующее: <img id="one" src="pictures/one.jpg" **class="picture1**"> также можете удалить id, оно вам не понадобится
- В файле css пишем следующее: (Сверху css, внизу html)

```css
.picure1{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/imagesq=tbn:ANd9GcQrUtWlQnnCmf2kIAQ3IFemxc_c_D4T3qtHwQ&usqp=CAU" class="picure1">
```

(Добавляем стиль фото здесь, ширину высоту и т.д)
}

Надеюсь помог вам. Если остануться вопросы или код не работает, пишите
Хорошего дня!

Comment: Не) Всё так и остаётся. Хз почему